# Finding rasters overlapping polygon shapefile

Tags: raster, pyqgis, polygon, big-data

I have 10,000 rasters but I only need 1000 of them but do not know which 1000.

The 1,000 I need to utilize overlap a vector polygon shapefile and another single raster I have (well the value of 1 in this raster). The polygons are thousands of small multipart polygons.

I cannot load all 10,000 at once and pick out 1000 that overlap manually.

How do I collect the 1,000 I need and get them into another folder or similar or get rid of the 9,000 I do not need and get them moved out?

I suppose I could iterate an extract by mask or similar but then what about the ones with no overlap at all.

Comment: Select by bounding box first, then only extract by mask on the ones that might overlap

Answer (score 2):

I like to use PyQGIS (much easier than ArcPy) for problems like this. Zoom to your polygon and the raster overlapping current extent will be copied to a folder:

```py
import os
from shutil import copyfile
rasterfolder = r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/grid50m/Hillshades/'
copy_to = r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/out/'

mapextent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()

for root, folder, files in os.walk(rasterfolder):
    for file in files:
        fullname=os.path.join(root, file)
        if fullname.endswith('.tif') and QgsRasterLayer(fullname).extent().intersects(mapextent): #If the file is intersecting current map extent, copy it
            print(file)
            copyfile(fullname, os.path.join(copy_to, file))
```

[image]

You can also use your polygon geometry instead of the map extent to see if it intersects the raster extent:

```py
import os
from shutil import copyfile

polylayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ok_ak_riks')[0]
polygons = [f.geometry() for f in polylayer.getFeatures()] #List all polygon geometries

rasterfolder = r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/grid50m/Hillshades/'
#copy_to = r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/out/'


for root, folder, files in os.walk(rasterfolder):
    for file in files:
        fullname=os.path.join(root, file)
        if fullname.endswith('.tif'):
            rasterlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fullname)
            if any (poly.intersects(rasterlayer.extent()) for poly in polygons):
                print(file)
                #copyfile(fullname, os.path.join(copy_to, file))
```

[image]